# Excel and hyperlink for local file

Tags: excel, hyperlink

Is it possible to make hyperlink for file located with same folder (or sub folder) like excel file? For example (...)/aaa.jpeg.
(...) would older with excel file and jpeg file.
I do not want to included full path with drive etc. So when someone copy folder with these file, links stay active.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When creating a link, the adress should already be in local form. If it's stored in `C:\Firstfolder\SecondFolder\ExcelFile.xlsx` the link should be only `aaa.jpeg`.

Comment: I want to skip "C:\Firstfolder\SecondFolder" part. When copy folder to another drive links still be working.

Comment: ok, now I see what you did there. I was assuming you were talking about creating a link via `Ctrl + K` shortcut. 
And also, yes. Try putting also the adress with `"` `=HYPERLINK("aaa.jpg";"aaa")`

Comment: Now I'm trying to modify next column where is VBA code implemented in link....=HYPERLINK(OnMouseOver("N:\Folder1\Folder2\"&C4&".jpg";B4);"PICTURE")  ===>  =HYPERLINK(OnMouseOver("Folder2\"&C4&".jpg";B4);"PICTURE")

Comment: I do not know what is the final target you have, but I recommend you to start using VBA for that. Another way to do it would be inserting the images in the comment field of the cell (`Ctrl + F3`)